# Using custom sections in app.config throws an exception in WPF

Tags: wpf, exception, app-config

I am very new to WPF and C# in general and using the app.config is confusing me.  It feels unnecessarily difficult to accomplish something pretty basic.  I just want to add a couple of data driven settings to my app and wanted to use app.config.

After a little research, it looks like "appSettings" is old and doesn't have type checking and "applicationSettings" seems to be deprecated (it's not even in the standard schema for VS 2012).  So, I am now trying to create a custom config section.  I wrote a very simple one based on examples but it throws a TypeInitializationException during launch.  I am staring at the code, but don't see what's wrong.

app.config file:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="applicationConfig" type="MyApp.ApplicationConfig, MyApp"/>
</configSections>

<applicationConfig
  UseLocalhost="true"
  WebServer="http://www.someserver.com"
  MachineId="999"/>
```

C# code:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class ApplicationConfig : ConfigurationSection
    {
        public ApplicationConfig()
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationConfig GetConfig()
        {
            return (ApplicationConfig)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("applicationConfig") ?? new ApplicationConfig();
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("UseLocalhost", DefaultValue = false, IsRequired = false)]
        public bool UseLocalhost
        {
            get { return (bool)this["UseLocalhost"]; }
            set { this["UseLocalhost"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("WebServer", IsRequired = true)]
        public string WebServer
        {
            get { return (string)this["WebServer"]; }
            set { this["WebServer"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("MachineId", DefaultValue = 999, IsRequired = false)]
        public int MachineId
        {
            get { return (int)this["MachineId"]; }
            set { this["MachineId"] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like exception is thrown by some other code - not the config section class that you quoted. TypeInitializerException is thrown by static constructors or static field initializers, neither of which your code has. How do you call GetConfig()? The bottom line is: look somewhere else in code, your section class and config file XML seem to be OK.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I am currently suspecting that it's because of the xsd schema check.  The build succeeds but there's a warning that it does not understand my custom attributes.  I used the "Create Schema" tool in VS but that lead to another problem where it complained that "configuration" is defined twice.  Probably once in one of the default schemas.  At this point, I am using "appSettings" and ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.  It's not ideal but works for now.

Comment: Don't think so... I pasted your code and config xml into my project and it worked - no exceptions. It must be something else, probably the part where you call GetConfig(), or even some code unrelated to your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I've found in the past that you can't have custom config objects in the same assembly as they're configuring. Try putting the objects into a separate assembly, referencing that new assembly in your project, updating the assembly of the custom objects in the .config file, and go from there

Comment: Hmmm... I put custom config object to the same assembly as config file's all the time - never was a problem for me...